# Reading a line from a file using perl

Tags: file, perl, directory

First off, I have to find the existence of the pass and fail files in the subdirectories. Then, I need to read the first line of the pass/fail file. I thought of separating the `$file1` and `$file` to differentiate it. I'm very new to perl so I know my approach is very bad.

I trying to figure out how to combine my current code to read the files I checked exists.

```
use strict;
use File::Find 'find';

my $file = 'pass.txt';
my $file1 = 'fail.txt';
my @directory = ('ram1','ram2');

sub check 
{
    if ( -e $_ && $_ eq $file ) 
        {                                                                      
            print "Found file '$_' in directory '$File::Find::dir'\n";                                     
        }  
    elsif ( -e $_ && $_ eq $file1 ) 
        {                                                                      
            print "Found file '$_' in directory '$File::Find::dir'\n";                                     
        }  
}
find (\&check,@directory);
```

Is it possible I use the code below for the first if condition? I know it doesn't work but I'm not sure what to do next as the fail and pass text are inside the directories.

```
if (open my $File::Find::dir, '<', $file){ 
my $firstLine = <$File::Find::dir>; 
close $firstLine;
```

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: The code you have doesn't make much senses. 1) `find` calls the callback for files it founds, so they necessarily exist. 2) Even if we accept that the files might not exist, why call `$_` twice? Why call it at all if `$_` isn't `$file` or `$file1`? That said, none of that is very relevant to your question, except I don't understand your question. Could you please describe what you are trying to achieve more clearly?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `find`.  If you want to open a file, just use `open`.  No need to `find` it first.

Comment: First off, I have to find the existence of the pass and fail files in the subdirectories. Then, I need to read the first line of the pass/fail file. I thought of separating the '$file1' and '$file2' to differentiate it. I'm very new to perl so I know my approach is very bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to look just in `ram1` and `ram2`, there's no point in using File::Find. That is used for recursive searches, meaning if you want to search all the subdirectories of `ram1` and `ram2`. (And for that, I'd use [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) over File::Find; it's much cleaner.)

```perl
my @dir_qfns = ( 'ram1', 'ram2' );

for my $dir_qfn (@dir_qfns) {
   for my $fn ('pass.txt', 'fail.txt') {
      my $file_qfn = "$dir_qfn/$fn";
      open(my $fh, '<', $file_qfn)
         or warn("Can't open \"$file_qfn\": $!\n"), next;

      defined( my $first_line = <$fh> )
         or warn("\"$file_qfn\" is empty\n"), next;

      print("$file_qfn: $first_line");
   }
}
```

If it's ok for a file to be missing, then you can ignore that error (`ENOENT`).

Similarly, you don't need to output an error message if the file is empty.

```perl
my @dir_qfns = ( 'ram1', 'ram2' );

for my $dir_qfn (@dir_qfns) {
   for my $fn ('pass.txt', 'fail.txt') {
      my $file_qfn = "$dir_qfn/$fn";

      my $fh;
      if (!open($fh, '<', $file_qfn)) {
         warn("Can't open \"$file_qfn\": $!\n") if $!{ENOENT};
         next;
      }

      defined( my $first_line = <$fh> )
         or next;

      print("$file_qfn: $first_line");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering. I really appreciate it! Meaning if I have a few more directories to search, is it okay to use `@directories`? If I can ask one more question, what is the difference between `die` and `warn`?

Comment: Of course. The foreach loop doesn't care if the scalars come from a list operator (`,`) or from an array. I've adjusted the code.

Comment: `warn $message` prints the message to STDERR as if you have done `print STDERR $message;`, except it appends the file name and line number to the output if the message doesn't end in a line feed. /// `die` throws an exception. That will end the program if the exception is uncaught. So `die` is kinda like `warn` plus `exit` under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (open my $f, '<', 'pass.txt') { 
  my $firstLine = <$f>; 
  close $f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's code does not make much sense. Perhaps OP is looking for something of next kind

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dir   = shift || 'some_dir_to_start_from';
my @files = qw/pass.txt fail.txt/;
my $match = join '|', @files;
my $regex = qr/\b($match)\b/;

files_lookup($dir,$regex);

exit 0;

sub files_lookup {
    my $dir = shift;
    my $re  = shift;
    
    for ( glob("$dir/*") ) {
        files_lookup($_) if -d;

        next unless /$re/;
        
        if( -f ) {
            say "File: $_";

            open my $fh, '<', $_
                or die "Couldn't open $_";
            
            my $line = <$fh>;
            say $line;
            
            close $fh;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this! This is kind of what I wanted but I need to filter out the rest of my files using this. Much appreciated!